# Galois: is $f(x)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$I have a function $f(x) = 2(x^2-x)+1$ and my question is, if this is irreducible in $\F_5$.

I now that $\F_5$ comes from $5=q=p^n$, $p = \Z/5\Z$, $n =\ $polynom with degree 1 (so something like $4x+11$ ...)

What happens to $x^2$ in $\F_5$?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have formatted your question, but there is a serious problem with the facts. $\mathbb{F}_{5}$ is just $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, no need to do anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, thanks for information!

Comment: You're welcome. And please take a look at the $\LaTeX$ editing I did, so that you can use it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial has roots in $\mathbb{F}_5$ and hence is reducible. We have
$$
2x^2-2x+1=2(x + 3)(x + 1)
$$
over the field $\mathbb{F}_5$. Of course, $x^2=x\cdot x$ is reducible, too.

Comment: So I try to factorize f(x) and look at every factor in F5 (and they all have a maximum degree of 1 here), If they are reducible in F5 my polynomial is reducible?

Comment: Any polynomial of degree $2\le n\le 3$ over a field is reducible if and only if it has a root. Now $-1$ obvioulsy is a root of $2x^2-2x+1$.